# Merging rows in Spark with special / complicated conditions

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
val df= Seq((100020,"GUID1","CreateWorkflow", "Workflow_Read", "None",  "10-02-2018" ),(100020,"GUID1","None","WorkItem_StateChange", "INPROGRESS", "12-02-2018"),(100020,"GUID1","None","WorkItem_StateChange", "INPROGRESS", "11-02-2018"),(100057,"GUID2","CreateWorkflow", "Workflow_Read", "None",  "10-05-2021" ),(100057,"GUID2","None","WorkItem_StateChange", "INPROGRESS", "12-05-2021"),(100057,"GUID2","None","WorkItem_StateChange", "INPROGRESS", "11-05-2021")).toDF("SerialNumber","GUID","UseCase","EventName","NewState", "Time")
```

which would look like:

```
+------------+-----+--------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|SerialNumber|GUID |UseCase       |EventName           |NewState  |Time      |
+------------+-----+--------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|100020      |GUID1|CreateWorkflow|Workflow_Read       |None      |10-02-2018|
|100020      |GUID1|None          |WorkItem_StateChange|INPROGRESS|12-02-2018|
|100020      |GUID1|None          |WorkItem_StateChange|INPROGRESS|11-02-2018|
|100057      |GUID2|CreateWorkflow|Workflow_Read       |None      |10-05-2021|
|100057      |GUID2|None          |WorkItem_StateChange|INPROGRESS|12-05-2021|
|100057      |GUID2|None          |WorkItem_StateChange|INPROGRESS|11-05-2021|
+------------+-----+--------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to merge rows for each set of SerialNumber and GUID such that one row with "Workflow_Read" merges with nearest row with "WorkItem_StateChange" and remaining row(s) with "WorkItem_StateChange" should remain as separate row in the result Timestamps of the merged rows shall be retained in 2 separate columns.
So result should look something like:

```
+------------+-----+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
|SerialNumber|GUID |UseCase       |NewState  |CreateTime|InProgresstime|
+------------+-----+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
|100020      |GUID1|CreateWorkflow|INPROGRESS|10-02-2018|11-02-2018    |
|100020      |GUID1|None          |INPROGRESS|None      |12-02-2018    |
|100057      |GUID2|CreateWorkflow|INPROGRESS|10-05-2021|11-05-2021    |
|100057      |GUID2|None          |INPROGRESS|None      |12-05-2021    |
+------------+-----+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Any idea how can this be achieved efficiently, ideally without using UDF?

Comment: is there always 1 **and only 1** row with `EventName`  equal to "Workflow_Read", per SerialNumber and GUID?  (like in the example)?

Comment: Correct. But there can be > 1..n rows with "WorkItem_StateChange"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create `row_number()` using a `Window.partitionBy().orderBy()` approach, as follows:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "row",
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("SerialNumber", "GUID").orderBy("Time"))
)
```

Then, manipulate as below, leveraging that row number

```
(
    df
    .filter(F.col("row")==1)
    .withColumnRenamed("Time", "CreateTime")
    .drop("EventName", "NewState", "row")
    .join(
        df
        .filter(F.col("row")==2)
        .withColumnRenamed("Time", "InProgresstime")
        .drop("EventName", "UseCase"),
        on=['SerialNumber','GUID']
    )
    .unionByName(
        df.filter(F.col("row")>=3)
        .withColumnRenamed("Time", "InProgressTime")
        .withColumn("CreateTime", F.lit(None))
        .drop("EventName")
    )
    .drop("row")
    .orderBy("SerialNumber", "GUID")
).show()
```

Output:

```
|SerialNumber| GUID|       UseCase|CreateTime|  NewState|InProgresstime|
+------------+-----+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
|      100020|GUID1|CreateWorkflow|10-02-2018|INPROGRESS|    11-02-2018|
|      100020|GUID1|          None|      null|INPROGRESS|    12-02-2018|
|      100057|GUID2|CreateWorkflow|10-05-2021|INPROGRESS|    11-05-2021|
|      100057|GUID2|          None|      null|INPROGRESS|    12-05-2021|
+------------+-----+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: I have one additional question. If "CreateWorkflow"/"Workflow_Read" row is missing, then merge should not happen. All WorkItemStatusChange rows should remain in the target DF. How can this be done?

Comment: maybe the easiest way here would be to split the original into groups that have and do not have that initial row. Do the above pipeline on the former, and then union in the latter.